# add words in a string array

Tags: c++, arrays, words

I am trying to read a file with separate columns and including each word of a column in an array. Some of them are numeral, other literals. For the literals, I am always getting and error of type conversion. Any idea?
Here follows the code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cmath>

int main ()
{
    string line; 
    int a=100;
    ifstream data;
    data.open("filename.txt");
    getline(data,line);

    int number[a];
    const char *at[3][a];
    const char *rt[3][a];
    int rn[a];

    for (int j=0;j<a;j++)
    {
        number[j] = stoi(line.substr(6,6));
        at[j] = line.substr(13,2);
        rt[j] = line.substr(13,2);
        rn[j] = stoi(line.substr(22,4));
        getline(pdb,line);
    } 
    return 0;
}
```

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Please correctly indent your code, that should be a better starting point!

Comment: What's the structure of your file?

Comment: `substr` returns a `std::string`. You cannot assign that to an array of char pointers (or whatever those variables are supposed to be).

Comment: Why aren't you using `std::string` and `std::vector`?

Answer (score 3):

A `std::string` is not a `char const*`. Use array item type `std::string` instead of `const char*`. You need to include the `<string>` header. Also include `<vector>`, and use `std::vector` instead of those raw arrays. Do note that the declaration `int number[a]` is **non-standard**, it uses a g++ language extension (namely C99 variable length arrays). Using `std::vector` you therefore also get more portable code.

---

E.g., instead of

```
int number[a];    // Non-standard
```

write

```
vector<int> number( a );
```

---

There are more details that could be mentioned, but it's unclear what's by design here and what's due to misunderstandings. So, if there's still a problem after making the transition to `std::string` and `std::vector`, I suggest making a new question instead of amending this one.

Comment: Thanks a lot Cheers! My biggest problem is to find a way to iteratively generate an array of words collected by reading a specific column. After declaring a string array (instead of a char array), how do I add new words to this string array? Should I declare it as "string at[a];"?

Comment: Like `vector<string> at(a)`. Except it could be a good idea to change the name to something more self-describing. And also because `std::vector` has a member function named `at`, so use of that name could be confusing.

Comment: Solved! Thanks again Cheers!